# Extracted URL not redirecting

Tags: html, url, redirect

I am looking at the following site: https://www.lg.com/us/press-release.

I need to get a link to go directly to the computers tab, and it needs to be a url.

I extracted and tried: https://www.lg.com/us/press-release#press-list5 however this still redirects.

Can someone tell me what the URL is to go directly to the computer tab please?

Thanks

Comment: @Peter they didn't

Comment: You are probably right: Stackoverflow wants us to be petty bean counters that make visiting the website as uncomfortable as possible. Under no circumstances you should  thank someone for giving voluntary help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a URL is going to work.  I believe there's some Javascript at work here.
Why?

Before/Unclicked:

```
<a href="#press-list5" aria-controls="press-list5" class="btn-tab" aria-selected="false" data-link-area="press_release_list-tab" data-link-name="computers">Computers</a>
```

After/Clicked:

```
<a href="#press-list5" aria-controls="press-list5" class="btn-tab active" aria-selected="true" data-link-area="press_release_list-tab" data-link-name="computers">Computers</a>
```

So once it's clicked, the list item has the active class added and the aria-selected attribute set to true.  So a URL with a bookmark doesn't look like it'll work.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to get a rss feed for just the computer info, I have a site which can make rss feed from url any ideas?

Comment: An rss feed is quite different to a webpage. Are you sure LG provide an rss excerpt of the page? Producing rss from a static page is different to producing rss from a page which calls js to inject dynamic content.

Comment: No I'm not sure if they do but I'm trying to make one if possible.